# Is inner join the same as equi-join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Can you tell me if inner join and equi-join are the same or not ?

Answer (score 49):

An 'inner join' is not the same as an 'equi-join' in general terms.

['equi-join'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Equi-join) means joining tables using the equality operator or equivalent. I would still call an outer join an 'equi-join' if it only uses equality (others may disagree).

['inner join'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) is opposed to ['outer join'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join) and determines how to join two sets when there is no matching value.

Comment: So, non-EqJoin is inner-join?

Comment: This is a nice explanation. Is there documentation or book that formally defines the concepts of equi-join?

Answer (score 23):

Simply put: **an equi-join is a possible type of inner-joins**

For a more in-depth explanation:

> An inner-join is a join that returns only rows from joined tables where a certain condition is met. This condition may be of equality, which means we would have an [equi-join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Equi_join); if the condition is not that of equality - which may be a non-equality, greater than, lesser than, between, etc. - we have a [nonequi-join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Nonequi_join), called more precisely theta-join.
>
> If we do not want such conditions to be necessarily met, we can have 
>   outer joins (all rows from all tables returned), left join (all rows
>   from left table returned, only matching for right table), right join
>   (all rows from right table returned, only matching for left table).

Answer (score 16):

The answer is NO.

**An equi-join** is used to match two columns from two tables using explicit operator **=**:

Example:

```
select *
  from table T1, table2 T2
  where T1.column_name1 = T2.column_name2
```

**An inner join** is used to get the cross product between two tables, combining all records from both tables. To get the right result you can use a equi-join or one natural join (column names between tables must be the same)

Using equi-join (explicit and implicit)

```
select *
  from table T1 INNER JOIN table2 T2
  on T1.column_name = T2.column_name

select *
  from table T1, table2 T2
  where T1.column_name = T2.column_name
```

Or Using natural join

```
select *
  from table T1 NATURAL JOIN table2 T2
```

Comment: Does it matter in natural join if the number of rows are different in 2 tables?

Comment: @Ahmn21Does not matter as same manner fot any other of join type

Answer (score 14):

The answer is No,here is the short and simple for readers.

**Inner join** can have equality (=) and other operators (like <,>,<>) in the join condition.

**Equi join** only have equality (=) operator in the join condition.

**Equi join** can be an Inner join,Left Outer join, Right Outer join

Comment: How can equi join be a left outer join or a right outer join?

Comment: It's strange but right join also working with >, < operator

Answer (score 1):

If there has to made out a difference then ,I think here it is .I tested it with DB2.
In 'equi join'.you have to select the comparing column of the table being joined , in inner join it is not compulsory you do that . Example :-

```
Select k.id,k.name FROM customer k
inner join  dealer on(
k.id =dealer.id
)
```

here the resulted rows are only two columns rows

```
id    name
```

But I think in equi join you have to select the columns of other table too

```
Select k.id,k.name,d.id FROM customer k,dealer d
where
k.id =d.id
```

and this will result in rows with three columns , there is no way  you cannot have the unwanted compared column of dealer here(even if you don't want it) , the rows will look like

```
 id(from customer) name(from Customer) id(from dealer)
```

May be this is not true for your question.But it might be one of the major difference.

Comment: What do you mean by unwanted compared column? If you will not select `d.id` in EqJoin then it will also work.

Answer (score -2):

**The answer is YES, But as a resultset**. So here is an example.

Consider three tables:

orders(ord_no, purch_amt, ord_date, customer_id, salesman_id)

customer(customer_id,cust_name, city, grade, salesman_id)

salesman(salesman_id, name, city, commission)

Now if I have a query like this:

**Find the details of an order.**

***Using INNER JOIN:***

```
SELECT * FROM orders a INNER JOIN customer b ON a.customer_id=b.customer_id 
INNER JOIN salesman c ON a.salesman_id=c.salesman_id;
```

***Using EQUI JOIN:***

```
SELECT * FROM orders a, customer b,salesman c where 
a.customer_id=b.customer_id and a.salesman_id=c.salesman_id;
```

Execute both queries. You will get the same output.

Coming to your question **There is no difference in output of equijoin and inner join. But there might be a difference in inner executions of both the types.**

Comment: This is not correct. One uses the ANSI 92 JOIN syntax (`FROM a JOIN b ON a.x = b.y`). The other uses the non-ANSI syntax (`FROM a, b WHERE a.x = b.y`). But both join on `a.x = b.y`, which makes them equijoins *because they use the equals sign*. A non-equijoin uses an operator other than the equal sign. That's all it means. Non-equijoin examples: `FROM a JOIN B ON a.x <> b.y` (joins on inequality), `FROM a JOIN b ON a.x BETWEEN b.y AND b.z` (joins on a range).