# Joins in relational database system

Tags: sql, join, database-performance

What is a difference between a use of Join keyword and using equijoin condition without the use of Join keyword? Does it cause any performance issue if Join keyword not used in SQL query? If yes then how is it related to performance.

Comment: An explicit `JOIN` is the right way to express an inner join, and has been for decades.  The comma in the `FROM` clause is archaic, and less powerful than the `JOIN` keyword.  But, in most databases, the two are compiled into the same code.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471063/is-inner-join-the-same-as-equi-join) might also shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **equijoin** returns only the rows that have equivalent values for the specified column.
An **inner join** is a join of two or more tables that returns only those rows that satisfy the join condition.